# Don't take it. You will lose it

Tags: grammaticality

He drank the milk from feeding bottle.

After finished drinking. He didn't want to give me the cap.

> "Don't take it. You will lose it."
>
> “Don't take it. You will make it lose.”

Do they grammatically correct and have the same meaning?

Comment: Your first version (not the second)( is syntactically valid, but not something a native speaker would be likely to say. More natural would be, say, *[No,] you can't keep it, [because] you'd / you would only lose it*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is really *correct*.  As FumbleFingers points out, the first is *grammatically* fine, but it's not really natural English.

> Don't take the cap, you'll **just lose** it.
>
> Give me back the cap.  If you **hold on** to it, you'll **just lose** it.

The second is incorrect because "make it lose" is ungrammatical, plus native speakers would not normally ask someone to "make [something] *lost*". "Make it go missing" perhaps, but that only in highly specific contexts.